# JavaScript is processing before it gets data from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

Stripe requires the validation of coupons on the server side rather than on the client side, so I've written a bit of code to do that, but I'm having some trouble with synchronizing the AJAX/JSON response.

In my controller I have a method called validate_coupon that takes a coupon code and verifies that it exists in the Stripe system and if it is valid. The function then returns a true or false as JSON.

```
def validate_coupon
    code = params[:code]
    begin
        coupon = Stripe::Coupon.retrieve(code)
    rescue => e
        coupon = nil
    end
    valid = coupon.nil? ? false : coupon.valid
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => valid }
    end
end
```

I have put the JavaScript that validates the coupon in this function. It appears to work, returning a 200 okay status, and the console.log here displays true or false correctly based on the validity of the coupon. However, there is a noticeable delay between the 200 status and the log message on the console.

```
function validateCoupon() {
    requestData = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "business/validate_coupon/"+$('#coupon_code').val(),
        dataType: "json",
        data: requestData,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        }
    });
}
```

This function is used later like this:

```
...
valid = validateCoupon();
console.log("validateCoupon returned " + valid);
if (valid) {
...
```

When I look at the log messages in the console this is what I see:

```
status = 200
validateCoupon returned undefined
true
```

which indicates that I'm processing the returned data before it's being returned from the server. I'd have expected the JSON to be returned at the same time as the status. Is there a way to make the JavaScript wait for the JSON?

Comment: This  is strange!.. As a temporary workaround you can set a timer function where you check for json. If json not found then again set the timer. Once json is recieved clear the timer. It will be like poling for json data..

Comment: Either you can use the `complete` handler of the `$.ajax` to handle the process done after calling `validateCoupon()`, or set `async : false` in ajax request

Comment: Thanks Muhammed. Setting async to false would have been the simplest way around this, however this has been deprecated since async interferes with user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return response;` is the return value of the function passed to `success:` not by `validateCoupon` -- `validateCoupon` function does not have a return value in this case.

To achieve your goal, you can do what @jzaa suggested -- with a minor edit:

```
function validateCoupon() {
    requestData = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "business/validate_coupon/"+$('#coupon_code').val(),
        dataType: "json",
        data: requestData,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            doStuff(response);
        }
    });
}

function doStuff(response) {
    console.log("validateCoupon returned " + response);
}
```

Comment: It was going to be difficult to make it work this way because there was already a bit of code that handled error display and preventing progress if there was an error. However, this helped as I ended up getting rid of the function and calling the ajax inline which let me handle everything neatly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What AJAX do is it just go for the ajax call and put it in stack due to its asynchronous behavior and move on.

After that when any json response comes it again go that success function and let your code in the success function executes.

This is what happening in your case first it executes then moves on and showing return as undefined and then goes to the success function and showing true.

what you can do is you can call the function in the success function what you want to do after you getting response.

```
function validateCoupon() {
requestData = "";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "business/validate_coupon/"+$('#coupon_code').val(),
    dataType: "json",
    data: requestData,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response;
        xyz();
    }
  });
}

function xyz(){
 ......
 ......
 }
```